# How do I convert a SQL server timestamp to an epoch timestamp?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know how to convert an epoch timestamp to a SQL server timestamp using DATEADD, but I am interested in a function that does the reverse of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `DATEDIFF` function like below :

```
select DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-11-20 23:12:02.000') as EpochTimeStamp
```

**Output :**

```
EpochTimeStamp
--------------
1511219522
```

You know already how can we get back the original date :

```
SELECT DATEADD(ss, 1511219522, '19700101') as OriginalDate

OriginalDate
-----------------------
2017-11-20 23:12:02.000
```